# Grails plugin for just some html pages and JavaScript

Tags: grails, plugins

I have some html pages with some JavaScript that I was wish to re-use across grails projects.  So it's all the plugin stuff is under web-app, nothing is under grails-app.

I pull the plug-in into a project but none of the html files in the plugin's root directory end up in the projects root directory.

When I unzip the war file, I can see the html page under

```
css/
images/
js/
WEB-INF/
...
plugins/myplugin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/myhtml.html
```

Meaning they are not very easily accessible.
It would be a pain to have to map this URL especially when the plugin version is hardcoded in the the path!

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make a MyAppConstants.groovy in your application with a STATIC_HTML_VERSION variable pointing to the static version you're using.

You can then use this in your template gsp.

This enables you to easily upgrade the static files by adjusting the version and you don't have any caching pain in the process.